# How to enter single user mode with a suddenly disabled root user?

Tags: sco

Suddenly, my Unix root user account seems to be disabled. At startup, the system presents a prompt to change the date, but the maintenance prompt to insert the password does not show. My OS is Unix SCO_SV 5.0.7.

I can't enter single user mode. How can I enter single user mode at startup?

Comment: The information provided is contradictory.  So far I don't think the problem has anything to do with `root` account or any form of restriction.  Can you instead focus on what you're actually getting on the screen?

Comment: Ok let me rephrase. My OS is Unix SCO_SV 5.0.7 in Identification prompt, i write my user account which is root, and when i enter the password it says root account disable, that's it, I can't enter. I need a way to enable it again.

Comment: One way to resolve this, is to enter in single user mode at startup, but it never gives me that prompt to do it, i just see the date prompt, and after that it continues with the boot process.

Comment: Is root the only user account you have access to?

Comment: No, actually i have another, the one i use for regular work which is 'pedro'. But with 'pedro' user it runs a COBOL program directly, which means i have no access to the system command line prompt.

Comment: Supposedly, pressing Enter at "Boot" will prompt you, but I have no way of verifying this. If you have some means of modifying the filesystem, you could temporarily replace the `initdefault` runlevel with `S` in `/etc/inittab`, but then if you could modify the filesystem you could just re-enable the root account, so I assume that isn't an option

Comment: it could be an option, could you please give a step by step procedure to do that?

Comment: All capital nicks look bad, I suggest to become simply "Pedro A Alfonso O", or simply "Pedro Alfonso".

Comment: @PEDRO was that comment directed at me?  If so, there should be a line in `/etc/initdefault` that contains `lbl:n:initdefault:`, where `lbl` is a label of up to four characters, and `n` is a runlevel, e.g. `2`.  You would want to change the runlevel to `S`.  Then reboot, re-enable the root account with `passwd`, and restore the original `/etc/inittab`.